# Modify a JLabel inside a void method

Tags: combobox, jlabel

Please i need your help, im trying to do that i want 3-4 days now and i cant.
I have 2 Classes MainForm and Class2.
I have a JLablel inside a method at Class1 and i want to modify it by pressing a button from the Class2.

```
public class MainForm {


    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainForm window = new MainForm();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainForm() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(400, 200, 488, 322);
        frame.setTitle("ShutDown");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);


/**
         * Time BOX
         */
        JComboBox<String> timeBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        timeBox.setBounds(73, 142, 90, 20);
        timeBox.addItem("Days");
        timeBox.addItem("Hours");
        timeBox.addItem("Minutes");
        timeBox.addItem("Seconds");
        timeBox.addItem("Right now");
        timeBox.setSelectedItem("Minutes");
        frame.getContentPane().add(timeBox);


        String getTimeBox = timeBox.getSelectedItem().toString(); 



        /**
         * The label info.
         */
        JLabel labelInfo = new JLabel("");
        labelInfo.setBounds(73, 209, 310, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelInfo);
        labelInfo.setText(getTimeBox);
}
```

and the Class 2

```
Class2

JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    }
```

i tried much and allways doesnt work, whats the code i need to write in that button to get the selectedItem from the timeBox (comboBox)
and put it to that label?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need references of both 
`JComboBox` & `JLable` objects in class 2.
Simple way to do that is to declare respective private members in `MainForm` instead of local members of `initialize` method & pass them in to the constructor or use setter method approach.
Let consider that the reference names are `jComboBox` & `jLable` respectively.
Now you can use following syntax to reference them from `actionPerformed` method of the anonymous class using this syntax `Class2.this.jComboBox` & `Class2.this.jLable` (jComboBox & jLable is object reference).